# Android Tabbed view within a tabbed view

Tags: android, android-tabs

Is it possible to have a tabbed view within a tabbed view as shown in the image below? Ive got a basic tabbed view set up, but am unable to create another tabbed view within in(the one below)

The green part represents a Relativelayout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOci3.png

Edit: I have tried use ViewPagers and the app seems to crash then
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339922/tabbed-view-within-a-tabbed-view

Answer (score 2):

You can implement [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) create a unique fragment and put it two times in the same LinearLayout with orientation vertical. You can user viewpagers inside the fragments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339922/tabbed-view-within-a-tabbed-view

Tried that. App crashes

Comment: Fixed the force close. But the second viewpager returns black, it doesnt seem to display its fragments
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373962/android-tabs-within-a-swipeview

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to make your own tabs for the inner tabbed view. Make a fragment that has three buttons styled to look like tabs, and then a frameLayout below. Each time the user clicks a button, replace the fragment in the frameLayout with the desired fragment.

EDIT:  Implement tabs in the standard way. Check out this link, for example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_navigation_tab

In your activities view, have two layouts. A relativeLayout on top, and a frameLayout on bottom. When the user clicks a tab, change the fragment in frameLayout. For example:

```
// Set up the action bar to show tabs.
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// for each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section1)
    .setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section2)
    .setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_section3)
    .setTabListener(this));
```

Then in the onClick method do something similar to this:

```
    @Override
  public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the
    // container view.
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER,
        tab.getPosition() + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();  //Change R.id.container to be your frame layout!!
  }
```

BUT only change the frame layout, and don't touch the relative layout.

The fragment that you put into your frameLayout will be similarly nested. It will have a bar of buttons at the top, and a framelayout inside it. When the user clicks a button, put yet another fragment into the frameLayout.

Comment: Yup. But I want the green part to remain constant and only want the bottom part to be switchable

Comment: looking online. Any links? Found a similar problem in ux.stackexchange, but no code.

Comment: used viewpager as that takes care of the touch and slide animation. but app seems to crash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339922/tabbed-view-within-a-tabbed-view